# How to generate javadoc for unit tests in netbeans

Tags: unit-testing, netbeans, junit, javadoc

I'm using Netbeans (currently 6.7) and I really like how I can generate javadoc from my source code. However my tests also have documentation (valuable documentation!). Is there anyway I can generate javadocs (ideally for both at the same time).

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

JUnit tests are productive, normal Java Code. They may contain normal JavaDoc comments.

Why don't you treat them like normal Java Code? Just run `javadoc` over this package and you're done.

You can generate your JavaDoc via the Build Menu.

Good luck!

Comment: Hi, I'm not sure you're familiar with netbeans and it's folder project structure. Tests are kept in a different directory than the other source code so you can't just run 'javadoc', I'd need to know how to run javadoc on two directories that hold the same packages and have javadoc merge them. Also, there is no Build Menu in Netbeans. You can generate javadoc for the src dir using the run menu but I want both src + tests. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Adding the following Ant target to build.xml does the trick for me:

```
    <target depends="init" name="-javadoc-build">
    <javadoc additionalparam="${javadoc.additionalparam}" author="${javadoc.author}" charset="UTF-8" destdir="${dist.javadoc.dir}" docencoding="UTF-8" encoding="${javadoc.encoding.used}" failonerror="true" noindex="${javadoc.noindex}" nonavbar="${javadoc.nonavbar}" notree="${javadoc.notree}" private="${javadoc.private}" source="${javac.source}" splitindex="${javadoc.splitindex}" use="${javadoc.use}" useexternalfile="true" version="${javadoc.version}" windowtitle="${javadoc.windowtitle}">
        <classpath>
            <path path="${javac.classpath}:${javac.test.classpath}"/>
        </classpath>
        <fileset dir="${test.src.dir}" excludes="*.java,${excludes}" includes="${includes}">
            <filename name="**/*.java"/>
        </fileset>
        <fileset dir="src/try" excludes="*.java,${excludes}" includes="${includes}">
            <filename name="**/*.java"/>
        </fileset>
        <fileset dir="${src.dir}" excludes="*.java,${excludes}" includes="${includes}">
            <filename name="**/*.java"/>
        </fileset>
        <fileset dir="${build.generated.sources.dir}" erroronmissingdir="false">
            <include name="**/*.java"/>
            <exclude name="*.java"/>
        </fileset>
    </javadoc>
    <copy todir="${dist.javadoc.dir}">
        <fileset dir="${src.dir}" excludes="${excludes}" includes="${includes}">
            <filename name="**/doc-files/**"/>
        </fileset>
        <fileset dir="${build.generated.sources.dir}" erroronmissingdir="false">
            <include name="**/doc-files/**"/>
        </fileset>
    </copy>
</target>
```

It's copied from nbproject/build-impl.xml with three changes:

- expand `classpath` to `"${javac.classpath}:${javac.test.classpath}"`
- add a `fileset` element with `dir="${test.src.dir}"` there are the normal netbeans *"Test Packages"*
- add a `fileset` element with `dir="src/try"` this is and extra source directory that my project uses. *(I don't know how to use a variable like ${test.src.dir} to refer to this directory.)*

Comment: for Netbeans 12.5 the trouble with this approach is that the javadoc block gets regenerated when related project properties change

Answer (score 0):

In Build-impl.xml there is a target named "-javadoc-build".  It contains two "fileset" sections.  Perhaps its possible to add a third section here.

Comment: I'm not sure whether this will work.  I'll let you know when I know more.

Comment: Instead of changing build-imp.xml, which is automattically generated change build.xml